# Defining a security model with implicit permissions / role

Tags: java, design-patterns, permissions, roles, shiro

I'm working on a roles/permission system for my web app and I'm unsure quite how to structure this.

Briefly. Users can access a number of Projects. This is a Participation and, amongst other things, a Participation has a Profile with a number of Rights. So these are Rights specific to a User within a Project. A Participation also has a Type (Admin, Support, etc.).

A Profile is based on a Role. Roles (perhaps poorly named) are effectively standard Profiles with default rights configurations defined in advance by admins. When creating a new profile one selects a Role to act as a base and then, if needed, one adjusts the rights. Profiles aren't exclusive to one user.

So far, so good (or not! you tell me!)

Rights are grouped by context/subject. So for instance all rights to do with 'Project Tasks' are grouped together. I haven't modelled this because it's handled by the UI (not sure whether that's a bad thing).

Now my issue is as follows. Depending on the Participation Type, certain Rights are implicit and should not be disabled. So when creating a Role for a 'Support' Participation, the 'See my own support tickets' Right should be implied and either not shown, or shown disabled so that it cannot be changed. Whereas a different Participation Type can optionally assign this Right or not.

I've basically got a spreadsheet with Participant Type / Right = Can't apply, Can apply (Selected or not) & Always applies. eg :

```
| RIGHT              | INV | SUP | ADM |
| ------------------ | --- | --- | --- |
| G_PROJECTS_READ    |  I  |  I  |  Y  | 
| G_PROJECTS_UPDATE  |  Y  |  N  |  Y  |
| G_PROJECTS_CREATE  |  N  |  N  |  Y  |
| G_PROJECTS_PUBLISH |  N  |  N  |  Y  |

Where Y = Type can toggle right on/off, N = Type doesn't have right 
& I = Implied i.e. Type has right and it can't be deselected
```

Any ideas/pointers as to how this can be modelled?

[image: model]

Many thanks,

AW

Comment: Have you considered removing complexity in your model by creating _all possible_ "participation roles" encoded in your spreadsheet, thus removing the need to model the third "type" of permission?  
Whoever is tasked with assigning a participation to a user could simply pick the appropriate role instead of potentially having to set one up (and possibly making a mistake) on the fly. So for your sample spreadsheet there would be a maximum of two possible choices (ignoring admin roles) you could tie to the participation type: `PARTICIPATION_READ_ONLY` and `PARTICIPATION_READ_UPDATE`

Answer (score 1):

Roles are basically pre-defined Profiles. As such various Roles will be just instances of Profiles created during app initialisation. We won't need Role as a separate class/entity.

Create an `interface IProfile` which has methods `Set<Right> getAllRights()`,  `Set<Right> getEditableRights()` and `Set<Right> getAllowedRights()`. Method `getAllowedRights()` gives default Rights which any User belonging to this Profile has (These rights can't be modified).  Method `getEditableRights()` shows which rights can be edited by an admin while creating a new Role.

Now coming to `Profile`, it is composed of `Type` and implements `IProfile`. Now you can implement the Profile as

```
public class Profile implements IProfile {
    //fields have their getters as well
    Set<Right> allRights; 
    Type participantType;
    Set<Right> allowedRights;

    public Profile(Set<Right> allRights, Type participantType) {
        //Set values in fields here
    }

    //This is used by UI to show admins which Rights can be altered for creating a new Role.
    public Set<Right> getEditableRights() {
        getAllRights - participantType.getRights
    }
    public Set<Right> setAllowedRights(Set<Right> addedRights) {
        //addedRights here is a subset of Rights given by getEditableRights()
        this.allowedRights = participantType.getRights + addedRights;
    }

}
```

Minus means the Set difference operation, Plus means Set Union here.

The default Rights for a `Type` are not given out in `getEditableRights()` but they are used to setup the total allowedRights in `setAllowedRights(Set<Right> addedRights)`

**Why I created an `IProfile`?**

In case you want to create a different kind of `Profile` which is composed of multiple other classes, when you will have `Type` and say `Reputation` (Reputation will also give user a fixed set of Rights), then you can just implement `IProfile` in a different way and your code dependent on `IProfile` still works the same way.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this. Still not quite sure how to store the Type/Right correspondance (statically in code enums, in db etc..). I updated the question to include an example of the correspondence table in mentioned. Also started looking into Apache Shiro as a potential framework to exploit...